# How to put multiple images in image keyword in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have two jobs `build_binary` and `build deb` and I want to combine both of them. But the issue is they both use different `images`. Former one uses `golang:latest` and later one uses `ubuntu:20.04` as shown:

gitlab-ci.yml

```
build_binary:
  stage: build
  image: golang:latest
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
  # tags:
  #   - docker-executor
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
  script:
    - echo "Some script"

build deb:
  stage: deb-build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
  # tags:
  #   - docker-executor
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  dependencies:
    - build_binary
  script:
    - echo "Some script 2"
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
```

I have tried in these two ways but it didn't work.

```
build_binary:
  stage: build
  image: golang:latest ubuntu:20.04
```

and

```
build_binary:
  stage: build
  image: [golang:latest,ubuntu:20.04]
```

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about `gitlab-ci` - for first hand you should understand what is `images`, what containers (docker) are in it's nature.

You cannot magically get `mixed image` that will be magically `ubuntu:20.04+golang:latest`. It's just impossible to make it from `gitlab-ci` file.

But you can create `your own IMAGE`.

You can take Dockerfile for ubuntu:20.04, at dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu

Then you can add commands to it to install golang inside this operation system `
After this you open golang:latest Dockerfile and copy it's installation process to ubuntu Dockerfile with required modifications.

Then you do `docker build -t my-super-ubuntu-and-golang` - see manual

Then you check it - `docker run` and check that it's normal ubuntu with `golang`

If all success you can push it to your own account to dockerhub and in gitlab-ci:

```
image: your-name/golang-ubuntu-20.04
...
```

> Suggestion to use `services` is very incorrect - `service` starts another image and connect it by network, so you can run `postgres`, `rabbit` and another services and use it in your tests for example:

```
image: alpine
services : [ rabbitmq ]
```

not mean that `rabbitmq will be started on alpine` - both will started - image of alpine and image of rabbitmq with local HOST name `rabbitmq`, and your alpine could connect to `tcp://rabbitmq:5672` and use it. It's another approach.

P.S.
For example you can look at https://hub.docker.com/r/partlab/ubuntu-golang
I think it's not image you really want but you can see how to make mixed ubuntu-golang image

Answer (score -1):

Using the image and services keywords in your.gitlab-ci.yml file, you may define a GitLab CI/CD job that uses multiple Docker images.

For example, you could use the following configuration to specify a job that uses both a Golang image and an Ubuntu image:

```
build:
    image: golang:latest
    services:
      - ubuntu:20.04
    before_script:
      - run some command using Ubuntu
  script:
      - go build
      - run some other command using Ubuntu
```

Comment: i think it's not correct - `services` are not started as merged `image` they are started as connected dockers, if you `image: alpine, service: [postgres]` it will not run postgres on alpine ))) - but author wants image that has both features - of ubuntu:20.04 and golang:latest ))))